# splitting a precise .ts piece with ffmpeg when doing -c:v copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

The goal is to generate HLS-compatible MPEGTS pieces from a mkv, copying the video with `-c:v copy`, but transcoding the audio.

However, since on input seeking (`-ss`) ffmpeg seeks to keyframe (for me, that seems to be nearest previous keyframe), **I'm getting N seconds of video without audio** before most of the segments, starting from the keyframe.

Possible solutions are:

1. Define segment offset/duration so that it actually matches the keyframes ; problem is I don't know how to quickly extract the list of keyframes and their offsets
2. Force ffmpeg to seek to the proper time somehow, and generate a keyframe there to start the segment with; **EDIT: I assume this is impossible since generating a keyframe changes all frames after that, which is impossible with `-c:v copy`**

Please do not suggest existing HLS solutions unless they demonstrate in source code a solution to the problem. ffmpeg has to be used, to generate each segment on-demand.

Comment: If you look at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy you'll see that seeking while copying is not possible to do accurately. Maybe you can calculate the frames needed to get to the keyframe, transcode the file up to the keyframe, and concatenate that with the file starting at the keyframe...

Answer (score 0):

For your solution 1. , you can use `ffprobe -show_frames` to get the frames. Keyframe information is part of the output. Option `-print_format json` is easy to parse.